# discretization in weka

Tags: data-mining, weka

I need to know when is the right time to do discretization in weka.I have data set,i need to create training and testing data samples from that data. Should i do the discretization for the numerical attributes before the sampling or after the sampling?

Answer (score 2):

This should be obvious.

As long as you **get the same result independent of the split performed** you can do it afterwards. But what is the *benefit* of that? Just do the preprocessing first then.

If you discretize by rounding - e.g. float to integer - then you should be fine (which is unaffected by the split). But if you discretize e.g. by quantiles, it should be obvious that you can screw up badly, because you will *discretize the different parts differently*!

Let's say you discretize data into two different values:

```
Input data    Type     Output value
0.9           good     1.05
1.0           good     1.05
1.1           good     1.05
1.2           good     1.05
---
2.1           good     2.20
2.3           good     2.20
2.2           good     2.20
---  SPLIT HERE ---
1.1           bad      1.20
1.2           bad      1.20
1.3           bad      1.20
---
1.9           bad      2.00
2.0           bad      2.00
2.1           bad      2.00
```

See, both "good" and "bad" were discretized into two discrete values, by using the average of each cluster of values. But as the averages for "good" and "bad" differ, the resulting attribute clearly exposes the true membership. The task of detecting "bad" has become substantially easier.

**Do not perform separate preprocessing, ever.**

Comment: Well let me clear the problem that i am facing, I have data set with two classes' values (good,bad).I am trying to get imbalanced class values.Therefore i separate the data set into two sets (one includes the good instances and one bad instances).When i do the discretization before and i merge the two sets,the results is satisfactory but if i do it afterward it is not that good. Could you  please help me explain this.Thank you in advance

Comment: What is a "good" result? What discretization are you doing? Does this permit overfitting / bias? If you discretize such that even = good, odd = bad, a classifier can learn your discretization method. So I would strongly advise against doing any kind of preprocessing on split data.

Comment: it seems that i am not making the problem very clear,i am not preparing this data set for classification task but i am preparing it for outlier detection task.i am developing a method for detecting outliers,Therefore i should have imbalance data set so i will be able to detect multivariate outlier (i.e. i want to detect the instances with good label as good,and detect bad instances as bad),That way i will have satisfactory results.The method doesn't deal with the numerical values therefore i need to discretize them into nominal values.I hope that will explain why i have to split the data.

Comment: Yes, so you have two classes: outliers and non-outliers. Same problem. If you discretize separately, the problem may become trivial, because it suffices to **detect the way objects were discretized**. Maybe it's even worse with outlier detection. Just do preprocessing first, then split.

Comment: i just want to make sure about the above example.For the input data ,why you did you cluster the values and found the average? it seems to me something wrong,because i think the values which are a round 2 should be together and the same way for the values which are a round 1,what do you think?

Comment: That is what I did, isn't it? Except for a typo that makes no difference.

Comment: i meant for the value number 12 and 13 which have bad label they have to be in the same cluster ,which contains 5,6,7 date points.

Comment: @Aiman not if you split your data first, which is what we are talking about! This is an example **why that is a bad idea**, after all. Yes, if you *would* first discretize, you *would* be fine.